# How to trigger node fs.writefile from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Okay so basicly i have html  from which im collecting input text and updating object with it

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="exportFile()"><span class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></span></a>
```

once triggered it is overriding textInput object

script.js - script file linked to index.html

```
textInput = { 
    text: '',    
};


const exportFile = () => {
    var x = document.getElementById("sampleeditor").innerHTML;    
    textInput = x;     
  };
```

now with my updated textInput object i want to pass it to app.js file which will handle write/reading json file. But not sure how i can trigger write/update function from app.js using script.js, if try export functions/modules rest functions used in script.js turning - "declared but value never read"

app.js - my node app file.

```
const express = require('express')
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path')
const textInput = require('./public/shit')


const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

//write to json 



const fs = require('fs');
let data = JSON.stringify(textInput, null, 2);

fs.writeFile('text.json', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data written to file');
});

console.log(textInput);


//read json



fs.readFile('text.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let textInput = JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(textInput);
});

console.log('This is after the read call');
////write to json 




app.listen(port)
```

Comment: I think you're confusing frontend and backend code, also try to rename this `require('./public/shit')` before posting on StackOverflow

Comment: From the client-side code you'd likely make an AJAX request to a server-side endpoint and include in that request the data needed by the server.  Then in the server-side request handler you'd perform your file system interaction.  Note that your current call to `app.get()` in the server-side code is an example of an endpoint/handler for a request.  You'll make another one (likely an `app.post()`) to handle your AJAX request.  Some tutorials on AJAX with Node/Express should help you get started.